# I found out I was the primary on a car loan and not the co-signer

Tags: credit, co-sign

I found out 6 years after I thought I co-signed for a car that I was actually the primary. The notes were paid at first, my daughter ended up doing a voluntary repo. What can I do?

Comment: Another lesson in why co-signing should never be done. Gift them couple month's payment, and if they still can't afford it, they can't afford it.

Comment: How did this come as a surprise? I haven't ever co-signed or had a co-signer, but I assume the section of the contract where you signed would be clear about your role. All other contracts I've signed had clear labeling about each party's role.

Comment: @Barmar: Two common ways it could come as a surprise: (1) OP was clear about the roles at the time of signing, but then didn’t think about it for several years (because all necessary actions were being handled by the daughter), and so had forgotten/misremembered the details; (2) OP was careless about it at the time, perhaps due to mental health issues, external stress, addiction, etc.  Obviously these are all things one should try to avoid in financial matters, but most people go through them at least occasionally — we’re human beings not robots.

Comment: @Barmar and unethical car salespeople who swap primary and secondary borrowers on the paperwork so the sale will go through, but lie about it to the buyers.

Comment: @Barmar: There's little practical difference between the roles. Both are fully responsible for the entire debt. The actual legal contract might not even make a distinction between them (the *purchase* agreement probably should identify whose name the title will be under, but the loan agreement doesn't need to care about that).

Comment: [[1]] It might be better to include the concern , rather than the blanket "What can I do" ... for what ? to get the car back ? to get back at your Daughter for tricking you ? for getting back your share of the Money ? for ?? I assume (going by the answers) that the concern is "credit rating" taking a hit. [[2]] I am curious how a Primary need not be involved in "voluntary repo" when Primary is the "owner" ? Surely , a co-signer can not take a car to go through the voluntary repo & the Primary has to be aware & agree to the voluntary repo ?

Comment: @Prem As others have mentioned, the designation of "co-signer" and "primary" is a matter of semantics rather than of any actual difference.  The car is collateral on a loan that either was in default, or in danger of becoming so, and a borrower offered to turn the asset over to settle the debt.  After 6 years, the car loan *probably* wasn't upside down, so the sale of the car *probably* covered the remaining balance.

Comment: I agree that there is no Difference , @MichaelRichardson , Credit rating will take a hit for all entities involved. I am only thinking about the "smaller" entity selling/donating/returning the Car without involving the "larger" entity. Currently , I think , "Primary" is the "first" entity listed in the loan agreement , while "co-signer" is the "second" entity listed in that loan agreement. All other Criteria are Equal. Would that be the over-view of what these terms mean ?

Comment: @Prem Exactly!  A huge issue is the apparent belief by many people that they are just doing a minor favor for someone when they co-sign and it is not understood by those many people that they are equally liable for the loan.  The wording of the question is an example of that belief in that the father is upset by being primary, not understanding that it makes no difference to his current situation which line had his signature.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson 100% agree. And an additional problem is that the lender is under no obligation whatsoever to inform the co-signer when the loan goes into default. Depending on how closely you monitor your credit score, by the time you find out, your credit could be anything from dinged to completely shot! And further, you could be on the hook to the lender for thousands in penalties on top of being fully responsible for the original balance and interest.

Comment: @stannius, you agree with Michael that there's no difference, immediately followed by pointing out a significant difference. (Unless you're saying that the lender has no obligation to inform *either* borrower that the loan is in default?)

Comment: @prl fine, I only 90% agree then.

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that cosigner means additional signer, not secondary signer There may be a single owner on the title but you have equal responsibility for the loan. If you cosign and you _aren't_ getting copies of all the mailings from the lender, call them and get that fixed. You may not want to know when things are going well; you definitely want to know the moment they aren't.

Answer (score 34):

> I found out 6 years after I thought I co-signed for a car that I was
> the primary.

This doesn't make a difference. If payments are missed then everybody on the loan documents will get dinged.

> The notes were paid at first, my daughter ended up doing a voluntary
> repo. What can I do

After the car has been repossessed, the damage has already been done.

Comment: I would think that if OP was primary, then the bank should have given then a chance to pay it off before agreeing to a repo.

Answer (score 32):

Reminder: "co" means "with". Not behind, not endorsing, not backup; you are as much a signatory to the loan as the "primary" borrower.

Primary and co-signer are equally on the hook. Both your credit ratings get dinged because you both failed to meet your obligations. "Voluntary" repossession is still repossession.

See many past answers about cosigning. Unless you are completely willing to make payments if the other person can't or won't, **do not** cosign. You are explicitly underwriting their finances with your own.

And if you decide to do it anyway, make sure the bank will send you copies of any statements or communications it sends to the primary. You want to know about any problems before they get out of control, even if your friend is embarrassed, or sure they can recover, and doesn't want to talk about it.

Comment: To emphasize that last bit — unfortunately, your credit is being dinged not because of some technicality, but correctly. By co-signing, you told the lender "I am guaranteeing you'll get your money even though I'm not the primary." The lender didn't get their money, which means from their perspective, you failed to make good on your guarantee. The fact that it's due to somebody else's action doesn't matter, because as cosigner you explicitly agreed that it doesn't matter. Your guarantee is now worth less than it did before, and the credit score reflects that.

Comment: @yshavit: Could a lender ding someone's credit without first offering that person a chance to repay any monies owed?  If Alex and Bob are separately recognized as parties to a purchase loan, and Alex offers to return purchased merchandise which is worth slightly less than the loan amount and the lender agrees, can the lender ding Bob without first offering Bob a chance to pay any difference between the outstanding loan amount and the value of the returned property?

Comment: @supercat That I'm not sure of.

Comment: I don't know if anything that would keep them from doing so. In any case, it's out of your control now

Comment: I can see a valid argument that it was the other signer's responsibility to let you know if they needed help.

Comment: @keshlam: which really reinforces the message to never co-sign for anything, ever. Because it puts your finances at the mercy of someone else, and not just their deliberate actions or unforeseen circumstances, but also their mistakes and oversights.

Comment: Offtopic: There's an Internet car service which is running an ad suggesting that finding a cosigner and buying a car you can't otherwise afford is normal. Unfortunately they underwrite one of my favorite radio programs. I need to write to the station and complain.

Comment: @keshlam: Would a voluntary repossession necessarily imply that the borrower "needed help"?  From what I've read, some lenders have in the last few years been eagerly offering to take back cars in exchange for waiving all future loan obligations even when the market prices of the cars were less than the nominal value of the loan obligations.

Comment: If that's what happened, one hopes they wouldn't have downgraded either party's credit record and there's nothing to worry about.

Comment: And what they really  should have done is sold the car and paid off the loan with the proceeds rather than "voluntarily repo". The former is a responsible choice. The latter is a failure to meet obligations.

Comment: @supercat I wonder if that's not a repossession, but a *sale*, with the sale price being whatever balance is still outstanding on the loan.

Comment: Doesn't matter what you call it. If they dinged one person's credit rating for not being able to complete the loan, they will ding the other. And frankly, since the bank wants the money rather than the car, they are right to do so. As I said: If this isn't what you want on your record, sell the car yourself and pay off the loan.